Is this a valid usage of suspended hyphen?
Original example:
"Computer Science and Data Science"
Which reduction is correct?

"Computer and Data Science"
"Computer- and Data Science"


Why would you use a hyphen here? What rule have you been taught for suspended hyphen? Have you done any research? Have you read any of these questions?

@StuartF I've tried researching but I haven't completely understood all valid and invalid scenarios. English is not my native language (hence I haven't been taught any rule regarding suspended hyphen). Perhaps you could try answering the question instead of being coarse towards me.

The general rule is that you only use a suspended hyphen if the original word was either a compound word or hyphenated. Since you don't write "Computer-Science" or "Computerscience", you don't use a hyphen when splitting it up.

This question and answer explains how suspended hyphens work.
